# Did Antarctica remain entirely unvisited by humans until the early 19th century?

Tags: ancient-history, archaeology, exploration, age-of-discovery, antarctica

Antarctica today is covered permanently by thick layers of ice, making it extremely inhospitable to humans. And, unlike the Arctic regions,  it had no indigenous population of humans when modern man arrived there. (Presumably because unlike the Arctic regions, getting to Antarctica involves a danger-fraught journey over the open ocean, and once you're there, it's just as hard to get back.) See: [Antarctica has no indigenous population](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antarctica#History_of_exploration)

What do we know about possible ancient (or at least not modern) human settlement in Antarctica - perhaps during pockets of time when there was less ice, or people somehow settling **in the ice** - human extremophiles, as it were? Or, to expand the possibilities somewhat, settlement by some of the pre-human hominids in very ancient times, when there was perhaps less ice? Are there myths and legends suggesting such a possibility? Any archaeological finds that might indicate such a thing? Maybe at least along the coastlines which are not continually buried in ice? Do those exploring Antarctica today concern themselves at all with such a possibility?

We do know that there were periods in Earth's history when Antarctica was not covered by ice and would have been quite habitable, (see 
Lennart Regebro's citation: [A forest grows in Antarctica](http://www.highbeam.com/doc/1G1-4164401.html)) so it does have some history of habitability, but that history dates at minimum to 3 million years ago based on that source, long before hominids capable of settling in Antarctica arose.  So that period would not be relevant to the discussion. Also see: [Antarctica was not always cold, dry and covered in ice sheets.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antarctica#Geological_history_and_paleontology).

I have no 'conspiracy theory' agenda here - I am not suggesting, as some 'unorthodox...' (pseudo) researchers have, that there is some hidden secret civilization existing today in Antarctica that is the source of UFO's etc. That is nothing but science fiction IMO. I ask this question simply because it seems rather incredible to me, that although humans had already reached virtually every place on earth in prehistoric times, a whole continent existed that humans never reached. In recent times, we have learned so much about the scope and ingenuity of human life in ancient times and far flung corners of the earth, and so I wonder: Have we perhaps learned something about humans in Antarctica?

**Can we say with a degree of certainty (*i.e. barring some sudden, spectacular revolutionary discovery)* that Antarctica is an entire continent untouched by humans until modern man arrived there in the early 19th century?** See: [The first documented landing on mainland Antarctica was by the American sealer John Davis in West Antarctica on 7 February 1821,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antarctica#History_of_exploration)

(I am looking for more than just additional references to the wiki page which I already read - we can all find things in wiki - my hope is that on this site we can delve deeper and further. IMO wiki should not have the final word in all our historical inquiries.)

Comment: I think I already asked something similar.

Comment: @Anixx: pls provide the link for your similar question to this one.

Comment: It's amazing to consider, but it seems that we might know more about the Moon and Mars than we do about Antarctica.

Comment: somthing similar - http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/7393/why-antarctica-was-never-conquered-before-the-advent-of-the-modern-men/7398#7398

Answer (score 25, accepted):

We can be fairly certain that humans did not live on Antarctica, the continent, before the 20th century.

> Since about 15 Ma, the continent has been mostly covered with ice.

Ref: Trewby, Mary, ed. Antarctica: An Encyclopedia from Abbott Ice Shelf to Zooplankton. Firefly Books. ISBN 1-55297-590-8.

> Intermittent warm periods allowed Nothofagus shrubs to cling to the Sirius group in the Dominion Range as late as 3-4 Ma. After that the Pleistocene ice-age covered the whole continent and destroyed all major plant life on it.

Ref: Stefi Weisburd, "[A forest grows in Antarctica](http://www.highbeam.com/doc/1G1-4164401.html)". Science News.

Since the earliest member of the Genus Homo is younger than that (c:a 2.3Ma) Humans can not have been living there at that point. So earlier hotter periods are not a possibility for human settlements.

Humans also got the technology for reliable oceanic travel at the earliest around two thousand years ago, so a prehistoric settlement would not have been possible, and a settlement in the last thousand or so years would likely have been accompanied by legends, like the Norse settlements in Greenland.

Also, the cultures that colonized Greenland had a much less extreme climate to deal with than the antarctic climate, and perhaps more importantly, they could develop the technology for that gradually, while moving further north. A culture that settled Antarctica would have to go from at worst a climate where winters average around [freezing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tierra_del_Fuego#Climate), to a climate where winters average [-10C to -30C](http://www.antarctica.ac.uk/about_antarctica/geography/weather/temperatures.php). This a gradual development of tools to survive in that climate would not have been possible, which means settlements would not have been possible.

It is possible that it would have been reached by sailors in prehistory, but making a viable settlement in Antarctica is highly unlikely because of the forbidding climate.

As such we can be fairly certain that the first human to set foot on Antarctica did this in [the 19th century](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antarctica#History_of_exploration), although exactly who it was is disputed.

Comment: I accept this answer, though I disagree with some of its contentions: Even if Heyerdahl was right, difficulties getting to Antarctica would have been insurmountable-the brutal weather and ice would have been impenetrable barriers. Even today, getting there by sea is not simple. Only the airplane has opened that continent to us-still only to a limited extent. But in spite of your point re gradual adaptation, I would not rule out entirely the possibility of some sort of settlement after they had learned to adapt somewhere else, or some window of luck allowed them to tough it out for a while.

Comment: The comments are out of order because I consolidated them.

Comment: Of course, there is the claim that the Chinese went there in the 15th century (by Gavin Menzies). But his works are deemed of non-historical studies quality (which is certainly true). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gavin_Menzies. As said elsewhere, it is doubtful that a journey (coming back) reached such a place before the 18th century (the KonTiki experiment showed long journeys were possible with primitive maritime technology, but not in such dire conditions). Accidental landings in the 18th century by lost boats might have existed, but they left no written traces.

Comment: @Jean-ChristopheDubacq: Yeah, Menzies is simply making things up and then putting a reference on it that doesn't support the claim. His books are, at best, fiction.

Answer (score 14):

For reference, here is the official classification [from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climate_of_Antarctica) of the conditions necessary for a "pleasant" Antarctic day:

> **Condition 3**
>   Windspeed below 48 knots (55 miles per hour)
>   Visibility greater than 1/4 of a mile (402 meters)
>   Wind chill above −75 °F (−60 °C)
>   Description: Pleasant conditions; all outside travel is permitted.

Condition 3 is apparently the **best** forecast they give for most Antarctic stations, partly because of the great speed in which conditions can change. Note particularly the temperature requirement. Northern Quebec and Alberta never approached those temperatures in the 6 years I lived there.

Even with all our modern technology, it is difficult to maintain an Antarctic  station through the long winter.

The notion that a pre0historic settlement could have somehow transported sufficient fuel from (not Patagonia as it doesn't have trees; The Falklands maybe, or the Cape, or Tasmania) in order to survive even one winter I find absurd. Only our technology provides us with the luxury, and means, for such research.

Comment: The question of fuel you raise is indeed very important, close to a 'deal breaker'. But see citation above: "A Forest Grows in Antarctica" - which claims forests as recently as 3m years ago. And there is some vegetation there even today (very limited, I realize) and very importantly IMO, volcanic activity. I believe it is also possible to build ice tunnels that provide insulation and can be kept at fairly moderate temperatures with little fuel.(I read about that once, many moons ago but have no source on hand).

Comment: Also: Not sure the analogy to modern stations is entirely  valid: Neither modern man's knowledge of how to deal with extreme environments, nor his requirements, are analogous those of the ancient/indigenous people. Consider the Inuits, Amazon and African rain forest dwellers, etc..

Comment: That's the south pole though, so it's the most extreme. But yes, the antarctic has a much more extreme climate than Greenland. @Vector Inuits could adapt to that climate gradually, which you can't do with Antarctica.

Comment: @Vector: I truly believe you have no concept of the conditions. 1) If you sweat, you are dead. No if's and's or second chances, because you will lose all your body heat in minutes. The moisture of your sweat fills the air gaps in your clothing, destroys its insulating effect, and then freezes next to your skin.2) The caloric requirements to keep your body warm are 2-3 times that of a temperate climate (6000+ calories a day, up to 11,000 in some instances).: http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/health-17371543.

Comment: @Vector: Note that the reporter gets one detail wrong in that story: it's not the sledge-hauling that burns up the extra calories, but the cold. Since one cannot sweat, one cannot exert oneself. It is imperative to NOT SWEAT, so all actions must be performed at a very measured pace. None-the less, the body defends itself from the cold by, conceptually (Not literally, because the mechanics are a bit different), going into a type of permanent shiver.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: No, actually that is NOT the South Pole; that is every place on the continent except the Antarctic peninsula.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens-your physicist roots are showing - I see you are always looking at things from the thermodynamic perspective (on Venus to)- I am not qualified to argue. :-)

Comment: @Vector: Thermodynamics **is** life. Do you know the Gambler's version of the three Laws of Thermodynamics: (1) You cannot win. (Conservation of Energy) (2) You cannot tie. (Entropy always increases) (3) You must play the game. (No heat-sinks at absolute zero). Learn them like that and you will always remember which is which.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens OK, you are right, I understand now. It says very little of what the typical conditions are though, as they only bother themselves with if you are allowed to go outside in modern gear or not. I updated my answer with average winter temperatures at the coast. And Inuit would use fat as fuel: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kudlik

Comment: To chip in a biological perspective: Humans evolved to have one of the most effective cooling mechanisms of any mammal; something we forget in our air-conditioned lives. Put us in any desert with a big brain to find water and catch things and we can thrive. A sub-zero climate though... we do better than a cold blooded animal but we still need an energy source. Not a lot of trees or [sea cows](http://www.neatorama.com/2007/04/27/3-animals-we-ate-to-extinction/) in Antarctica.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers I would add that Antarctica is well protected by the Westerlies, a zone of westerly winds surrounding it from 30-60° S. These bands are named
"Roaring Forties", "Howling Fifties" and "Screaming Sixties", try to guess why.
Apart from mostly bad weather with regular storms of hurricane force and freak waves you must cross the oceans with continously decreasing temperatures and fields of pack ice. The only land near this regions is Patagonia in South America which is also quite inhospitable.

Under these circumstances it may be not so surprising that Antarctica was untouched until the l9th century.

Answer (score 2):

Patagonians reached the Falklands and Maoris settled Sub-Antartic Islands thus in one sense humans did reach the periphery of Antartica.

Comment: I'm not sure about the Falklands being 'ant-arctic'... Is there a source that they are considered so?

Comment: @CGCampbell The Falklands are not considered sub - Antarctic. South Georgia might be, but that wasn't reached until a lot later.

Comment: "There are remains of a Polynesian settlement dating back to the 13th century on Enderby Island in the Auckland Islands.[4][5][6][7] According to ancient legends, around the year 650 the Polynesian traveler Ui-te-Rangiora led a fleet of Waka Tīwai south until they reached "a place of bitter cold where rock-like structures rose from a solid sea".[8] A shard of undated, unidentified pottery, reported as found in 1886 in the Antipodes Islands, has been associated with this expedition.[9]"

Comment: @RayKerkhove could you provide a reference to the quotation in your comment and add that reference to your answer?

Answer (score -1):

If   Antarctica   had  no  ice  1.5   million  years  ago  or  500,000  years   ago,   perhaps   there  were   humans   on  Antarctica  then.   NASA   Imaging   over  Antarctica   has   a   story  to  tell.    Read  it  dudes.  Maybe  humans   migrated  north  to  South  America   and  later  into  N  America,   from  Antarctica   before  they  froze  to  death  at  onset  of  Antarctic  glaciation.  There  was   also  migrations   going  on  over  Beringia,  as   enough  evidence  for  that  these   days.  Oh,  a  fossil  swimming   reptile  has  been  found    recently in  of  all  places ,,Antarctica.    Was  there  some  evolution   going  on  down  at  South  Pole   before   Ice  Ages  set  in  there

Comment: Speculating that people could survive there is one thing. How did you imagine humans getting **to** Antarctica in the first place?

Comment: Sources would improve this answer; this is merely speculation without evidence.

Comment: Current thinking is that the human species has only existed for around 200,000 years.  More importantly, the oldest known boat is around 10,000 years old, and it was a dugout canoe that obviously couldn't have gotten anywhere near Antarctica.